# 'int' object has no attribute 'sub'?

Tags: python, error-handling

Hey could you guys help me out? This is a very important program and I ran into this error?

## start of program

```
import random
import operator
print("Welcome to the Primary Maths Test!")
while True:
    number1 = random.randint(1,12)
    number2 = random.randint(1,12)
    operator = random.randint(1,3)
    if operator == 1:
        operator.add(number1,number2)
    else:
        operator.sub(number1,number2)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid you haven't provided enough information for us to help you - we don't even know what language you're working in. You should also read the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) so you can format your post more readably... and tell us exactly where the error occurs, and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Oh wow, I think it posted properly sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you override the module 'operator' with integer variable 'operator', just give the variable another name and it will work.